# Javascript syntax error using Cordova in Android 6

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using Cordova and have a syntax error in Android API 23 (6 Marshmallow).
Everything works fine on API 28 (9 Pie) and API 21 (5 Lollipop) but with API 23, I have those errors :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I'm using vanilla JS and nothing else.

What is the problem? And how could I solve it?

Comment: What's the node version your using?

Comment: @Prawinsoni I'm using v12.13.0

Comment: okay, the problem was with node 5. Did you try with strict mode?

Comment: @Prawinsoni apparently the problem was an incompatibility of ES6 in API 23, 'strict mode' was also a problem. I found a solution, but it's possible that it doesn't work on older phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem come from an incompatibility of ES6 in API 23.
To resolve this, I use [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

`sudo npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

Create a .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "sourceType": "script" //To remove 'use strict' of generated js files
}
```

Then you can transcompile your code into es5 with this command
`npx babel src/js -d www/js`

It's possible to execute this command automaticaly with hooks.
Just create a .sh file (for example build.sh) and add the command to it.
Add the hook to the config.xml file
`<hook type="before_build" src="hooks/build.sh" />`